# sudo inside of a script with a command that needs input (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I want to make a script that changes screen brightness and, among others, need this command:

```
echo "$number" | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

The script asks me for my root password which i think is unnecessary for it only changes the brightness. I tried adding `sudo -S` and echo-ing the password but not only did i confuse myself with what input goes where, but the script writes out the `[sudo] password for user:` prompt which is anoying. How do i make the script runable by everyone (both from inside of the script and outside, i do this as an exercise to learn more)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might configure your system so that `sudo` does not ask for any password. I don't recommend doing this (put `ALL=NOPASSWD:` in your `/etc/sudoers` file at appropriate place), since it is a security hole.

But what you really want would be to make a [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) executable (BTW `/usr/bin/sudo` is itself a setuid executable). It is tricky to understand, and you can make huge mistakes (opening large security holes). Read also carefully [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) & [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Spend several hours to understand the *setuid* thing (if you misunderstand it, you'll have security issues). See also [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) & [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

For security reasons, shell scripts cannot be made *setuid*. So you can code a tiny wrapper in C which would run the script thru `execve` after appropriate calls (e.g. to [setresuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setresuid.2.html) and friends), compile that C program as a setuid executable (so `chown root` and `chmod u+s` your executable). In your particular case you don't even need to code a C program starting a shell command (you just should `fopen` the `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` pseudo-file then `fprintf` into it, and `fclose` it).

Actually, I don't believe that doing all that is necessary, because you should be able to configure your system to let your screen brightness be set by non root. I have no idea how to do that precisely (but that is a different question).

Comment: You can also configure `sudo` to allow just the command `tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to be run as root without a password.